# How to write a triple fraction with one missing line

Tags: math-operators, mathtools

I want to write a triple fraction with the first horizontal line missing. I tried doing it with a combination of \dfrac and \substack, or with matrices. But nothing looks similar to this:

[image: Text]

Does someone know how they did this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: With `\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath` in the preamble, one could use `\frac{\stackon{B}{A}}{C}`.  But you need to provide some more context on how you want this used.

Comment: The best way to deal with fractions is probably to use the `\genfrac` command provided with the `amsmath` package, the documentation for which includes that of `\genfrac`. I give you an example below.

Answer (score 8):

The following seems to exactly reproduce your picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
(\lnot B \lor \lnot C) \\
(B \lor \lnot C) \\
\hline
(\lnot C \lor \lnot C)
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Clearly, the OP needs a suitable way to write inference rules of sequence caculi in logic. The [bussproofs](https://ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs) package serves this and the [bussproofs-extra](https://ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs-extra) package gives more functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$(\neg B\vee\neg C)$}
\noLine
\UnaryInfC{$(B\vee\neg C)$}
\UnaryInfC{$(\neg C\vee\neg C)$}
\end{prooftree}

\begin{prooftree}
\Axiom$(\neg B \fCenter \,\vee\,\neg C)$
\noLine
\UnaryInf$(B \fCenter \,\vee\,\neg C)$
\UnaryInf$(\neg C \fCenter \,\vee\,\neg C)$
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you think the vertical spaces between first and second line are too large, then you can use `\extraVskip` to adjust it for which the default value is `2pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\def\extraVskip{0.5pt}
\AxiomC{$(\neg B\vee\neg C)$}
\noLine
\UnaryInfC{$(B\vee\neg C)$}
\def\extraVskip{2pt}
\UnaryInfC{$(\neg C\vee\neg C)$}
\end{prooftree}

\begin{prooftree}
\def\extraVskip{0.5pt}
\Axiom$(\neg B \fCenter \,\vee\,\neg C)$
\noLine
\UnaryInf$(B \fCenter \,\vee\,\neg C)$
\def\extraVskip{2pt}
\UnaryInf$(\neg C \fCenter \,\vee\,\neg C)$
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are some more examples in the [link 1](http://www.actual.world/resources/tex/doc/Proofs.pdf) (pp. 17-23), [link 2](https://mirrors.dgut.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/bussproofs/testbp2.pdf) and [link 3](https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/bussproofs-extra/bussproofs-extra.pdf).

Comment: The vertical space between the first and second lines looks too large.  I'm not sure how this might be decreased, but that would be a good adjustment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I update the statements to your question. But in my opinion, it's not necessary to adjust it since the difference is very small in printing although it looks large in the scaled picture right now .

Comment: Thank you.  (Admittedly, I'm very fussy about spacing.  Too much time spent adjusting such things in my professional capacity, as TeX support person at the AMS before I retired.)

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility with `stackengine`:

```
    \documentclass {article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
    \setstackgap{S}{1ex}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \frac{\Vectorstack{(\neg B \vee \neg C)\\ (B \vee \neg C)}}{(\neg C \vee \neg C)} \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To display a fraction without horizontal line (or not!), you can use `\genfrac`. You can chose different styles (displaystyle, textstyle, etc. )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{%
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}% displaystyle
    {(\neg B \vee \neg C)}%
    {(B \vee \neg C)}%
  }%
  {(\neg C \vee \neg C)}%
  =%
  \frac{%
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}% textstyle
    {(\neg B \vee \neg C)}%
    {(B \vee \neg C)}%
  }%
  {(\neg C \vee \neg C)}%
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: genfrac-frac]

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

- use of `\splitfrac` defined in `mathtools`
- use of `gathered` defined in amsmath as well in its supersede `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{
\splitfrac{(\neg B \vee \neg C)}
          {(B \vee \neg C)}}
        {(\neg C \vee \neg C)}
= \frac{\begin{gathered}
            (\neg B \vee \neg C)\\
            (B \vee \neg C)
        \end{gathered}}
        {(\neg C \vee \neg C)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Too much vertical space between the first two lines in the one on the right.  Vertical spacing is good in the one on the left, but simple center alignment would be better horizontally.